# Javascript inline function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about inline function call in javascript.

This example works:

```
<button onclick="{alert($(this).text());}">Testing</button>
```

While this is not working:

```
<button onclick="function(){alert($(this).text());}">Testing</button>
```

My question is - why is the second case not working and the first one does?

I've come accross this issue, using jQuery-UI droppable:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Droppable is also using this syntax (without `function()`). Why is that?

Comment: You're making an anonymous function, not calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets break this down sample by sample

```
<button onclick="{alert($(this).text());}">Testing</button>
```

This would be same as doing the following in pure javascript.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  {
    alert($(this).text());
  }
});
```

It's a bit weird to add extra braces like that but it is fully allowed and the code within will be executed. For your second sample this gets really weird though.

```
<button onclick="function(){alert($(this).text());}">Testing</button>
```

This would be the same as this.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  }
});
```

In other words, when you click on the button you'll declare a new function but you'll never call it. To get around this you would need to wrap it in paranthesis and then call `.call(this)` on the function to execute with the same `this` as the caller.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  (function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  }).call(this);
});
```

Or in your style.

```
<button onclick="(function(){alert($(this).text());}).call(this)">Testing</button>
```

Comment: `}).bind(this)();` should be rewritten as `}).call(this)`, otherwise you're needlessly creating a new function from the anonymous one before calling it, instead of just calling the anonymous function itself.

Comment: You're right, that would be better. I'll update the sample.

Answer (score 6):

```
<button onclick="function(){alert($(this).text());}">Testing</button>
```

That is equivalent to:

```
yourButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    };
});
```

Can you see why it's not working now?

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the best answer for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

**example 1**

Your passing statement. So it's working.

**example 2**

Your passing callback function. Javascript onclick doesn't support callback.

About droppable, droppable is a jquery plugin so it will support callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Because the brackets are superfluous, and likely being ignored:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alert($(this).text());">Testing</button>
```

If you want to encapsulate it in a function and run it as such, I suppose it would need to be self-invoking:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="(function(){alert($(this).text());})();">Testing</button>
```

But then the `this` value gets unbound.

The `droppable` syntax is something completely different-- you can think of it like this:

```
var configObj = { // this isn't a function, it's a config object
  drop: function( event, ui ) {}  // this is a function value of the property drop
}
$( ".selector" ).droppable(configObj);
```